# Is there a delay between enabling a peripheral timer and the timer actually starting its count? What is this delay and what causes it?

Tags: arm, stm32, cortex-m

I am trying to configure a timer (TIM9) and its interrupt handler to single step through a program. My approach is to first interrupt the first instruction, and then in the interrupt handler configure the timer so that it triggers an interrupt right after returning from the ISR.

Right now I'm still trying to get the first step correctly.

This is the piece of sample code I'm working with right now. I have configured the timer to generate an interrupt when its counter is equal to some compare value.
I set the compare value equal to 1 so that the code gets interrupted after 1 cycle of the timer. According to the reference manual the counter starts counting 1 cycle after setting the enable bit so I added a NOP.

```
  /*
   * TIM9 is configured to generate an interrupt when counter s equal to compare value
   */
  TIM9->CCR1 = 1;           // set compare 1 value to 1
  TIM9->CR1 |= 1;           // enable TIM9
  __ISB();                  // flush pipeline
  __asm volatile ("NOP");   // from reference manual: counter starts counting 1 cycle after setting CEN bit
  __asm volatile("MOV r8, #1 \n\t"); // expect to interrupt this instruction
  __asm volatile("MOV r8, #2 \n\t");
  __asm volatile("MOV r8, #3 \n\t");
  __asm volatile("MOV r8, #4 \n\t");
```

To verify that the correct instruction got interrupted I used GDB to check the content of register r8 after entering the interrupt handler, and I found that it is actually equal to 6. This implies that there is a much longer delay than 1 cycle or that I'm simply missing something.

I can simply add 5 NOP instructions before the first MOV instruction so that the interrupt occurs at the right time but I don't understand why this is neccessary. As far as I know the code as I have it right now should generate an interrupt during the first MOV instruction.

Why am I getting this behavior? Why does there seem to be such a long delay between enabling the timer and the interrupt being generated?

Is this maybe because there is a delay between the counter value equaling the compare value and the actual generation of the interrupt?

Or is it possible that this has something to do with how the pipeline works?

I have set the prescaler of the timer to 0 and there is no internal clock division happening so the timer should have the same frequency as the system clock.

Comment: writes are fire and forget, from the first bus controller on the far side of the arm it can take and likely takes more than one clock to get to the timer to perform the write in the mean time the arm continues.  and the processor and the bus and the peripherals can all be running at different clock rates making the number of cpu clocks go by faster than these other transactions.  then there is the timer can be configured to run off of different clocks is it running off of a clock slower than the processor.

Comment: this is pipelined so you cannot assume an instruction takes one clock, do not mis-interpret any timing in any arm doc.  and this is fetching from flash most likely adding more potential delay.   There is no reason to assume the time to interrupt is deterministic in this situation.  If you make no other changes and have nothing in parallel it is possible if not likely to be repeatable, but you can make minor changes including using the same machine code in the same order and have that repetable result change (same clocks, same everything else, change alignment by a halfword for example)

Comment: even with the bus and peripheral on the same clock there are delays in the system.  for example make a loop that writes the control register do that a few thousand times and time it with systick..unroll it some if you like to avoid the pipeline effects from the branch.

Comment: stm32s vary widely, in general specify the chip, arm, cortex-m, stm32, tim9, are too broad

Comment: did you preserve r8 so that this code does not trash it?

Comment: did you examine the disassembly, for a test like this you want that timer enable to be in asm along with the instructions that follow.  if this were a useful test, it is interesting, but because so much is non-deterministic, the results have little value.  If you are trying for some form of timed delay that is accurate and not just greater than, not sure if you are going to get there...

Answer (score 2):

I do not know why you want to check it. It works as it is supposed to work.

1. NOP is the worst way of adding the delay. It is something different than the 8 bits AVR`s NOP. It is instantly flushed off the pipeline and it should be used only as padding.
2. 1 clock after CEN means one timer clock, not the HCLK clock (they can be the same)
3. CCRx = 1 means two clocks.
4. If you run from FLASH - wait states are added
5. Pipeline execution status is not easy to determine. The actual instruction interruped does not have to be the one you actually think. The time of the interrupt is determined but not the actual instruction.

Comment: All of this is correct.  The elephant in the room is OP's first sentence: "I am trying to configure a timer (TIM9) and its interrupt handler to single step through a program".  As this answer clearly shows, you can't.